# XML to HTML Methods

Tags: html, xml

What are proven methods of parsing and displaying content from an XML file in HTML? Are there ways to do this with PHP? Javascript? Is that how most web applications interact with APIs, through the parsing of response XML files?

Comment: Your question is too vague. XML is just a container format, it can contain anything with arbitrary tree structures. Your question is therefore similar to *how can I convert XML to binary files*.

Comment: How can I parse values from the XML file and display them inside of HTML tags?

Comment: I think the question is about pretty-printing an XML tree with nice colors and indentation, the way most web browsers display them by default.  Right?  If this is indeed the question, write an XSLT or use the alternatives that GolexTrol suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse XML using JQuery. You can use regular jquery selectors to find nodes in the XML file. Then you can use Javascript/JQuery to insert the data into your HTML file. 
Same goes for PHP's SimpleXML. In fact, you can use any XML reader to read the XML and can use any method you like for outputting it.

If you got a matching XSLT, you can *transform* the XML to HTML without writing code. That is, you will have to write the XSLT, which is probably just as much work...